# How can I delay a few seconds in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried using sleep() in Darwin however that seems to delay the execution of my previous function.

```
SomeStruct.display(argument)
sleep(1)
```

If I write like this, the display function will be delayed for 1 second before being executed. I wonder if there were functions that operate as delay() in C++ that can just create a pause for a certain period of time without affecting previous execution.

edit:
This is my code:

```swift
cardModel.turn(card: card)
            if card.pairID == cards[faceOnID!].pairID {
                print("Paired")
            } else {
                print("Not Paired")
            }
            print("executed")
            do { sleep(1) }
            cardModel.turn(card: card)
            cardModel.turn(card: cards[faceOnID!])
            faceOnID = nil
```

While executed is printed, the turn() didn't take effect in contentview...
this is the code of the turn() function:

```swift
mutating func turn(card: Card) {
        cards[cards.locateFirstElement(matching: card)!].isTurnedOver.toggle()
    }
```

and this is the code of the locateFirstElement() function:

```swift
extension Array where Element: Identifiable {
    func locateFirstElement(matching item: Element) -> Int? {
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            if self[i].id == item.id {
                return i
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's affecting `display`?  Have you tried printing to the debug console between the two calls?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, the display() function affects the contentview, however, the change took place after a few secs. Therefore I can infer that the execution has been affected by sleep()

Comment: It's more likely that the `display` completed but the `sleep` stalled the main thread before UI updates happened.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have edited my questions and added a few lines of code. If the question is as you described, is there any workaround or suggestions I can take?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no need to reinvent the wheel, there is a function to get the index for a given predicate

```
mutating func turn(card: Card) {
    guard let cardIndex = cards.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == card.id}) else { return }
    cards[cardIndex].isTurnedOver.toggle()
}
```

Second of all, **never** `sleep`, don't, use asynchronous API to avoid blocking the current thread

```
cardModel.turn(card: card)
if card.pairID == cards[faceOnID!].pairID {
    print("Paired")
} else {
    print("Not Paired")
}
print("executed")
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
    self.cardModel.turn(card: card)
    self.cardModel.turn(card: cards[faceOnID!])
    self.faceOnID = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sleep, which delays the execution of your previous function, look into using Timer (formerly NSTimer). I really like how it is explained here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer

However, if you really need the delay in the current thread, you can do the following:

```
do {sleep(1)}
```

Comment: It is wried because I added a print() before do{sleep()} and it turns out that the print() has been executed but the display() function is not executed properly (btw I edited the questions and added a few lines of code, hope that helps)